# How to disable word splitting during command substitution?

Tags: zsh, command-substitution

How can I disable word-splitting during command substitution? Here's a simplified example of the problem:

```
 4:00PM /Users/paymahn/Downloads
 ❯❯❯ cat test.txt
hello\nworld
 4:00PM /Users/paymahn/Downloads
 ❯❯❯ echo $(cat test.txt )
hello
world
 4:00PM /Users/paymahn/Downloads
 ❯❯❯ echo "$(cat test.txt )"
hello
world
 4:01PM /Users/paymahn/Downloads
 ❯❯❯ echo "$(cat "test.txt" )"
hello
world
```

What I want is for `echo $(cat test.txt)` (or some variant of that which includes command subsitution) to output `hello\nworld`.

I found https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html which says at the bottom `If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the results.` but I can't seem to make sense of that. I would have thought that one of the examples I already tried conformed to that rule but I guess not.

Comment: Are you sure you're running Bash? `echo $BASH_VERSION`?

Comment: ...ooops. I'm using zsh. I guess I had assumed that zsh and bash work the same.

Comment: If the result of the first cat is literally "hello\nworld", then the rest of the examples don't make sense. Please show a hexdump of your file `hexdump -C test.txt`.

Comment: Yeah, it's a zsh problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Having a literal `\n` get changed to a newline isn't about word splitting, but `echo` processing the backslash. Some versions of `echo` do that, some don't... Bash's `echo` doesn't process backslash-escapes by default (without the `-e` flag or `xpg_echo` option), but e.g. dash's and Zsh's versions of `echo` do.

```
$ cat test.txt 
hello\nworld
$ bash -c 'echo "$(cat test.txt)"'
hello\nworld
$ zsh -c 'echo "$(cat test.txt)"'
hello
world
```

Use `printf` instead:

```
$ bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$(cat test.txt)"'
hello\nworld
$ zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" "$(cat test.txt)"'
hello\nworld
```

See also: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/170373)

Regardless of that, you should put the quotes around the command substitution to prevent word splitting and globbing in sh-like shells.
(zsh only does word splitting (not globbing) upon command substitution (not upon parameter or arithmetic expansions) except in sh-mode.)

Answer (score 0):

The echo implemented by zsh interprets escape sequences by default. The simplest solution is:

```
$ echo -E "$(cat test.txt)"
hello\nworld
```

or

```
$ print -r "$(cat test.txt)"
```

The correct solution is to use printf:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$(<test.txt)"
```

Comment: Note that in `zsh` one may prefer `echo -E - "$(<test.txt)"` or `print -r -- "$(<test.txt)"` in case the content of `test.txt` starts with `-f`, which ends up not being much shorter than `printf '%s\n' "$(<test.txt)"`.